# Converting Watlow 0-24V controller output to 0-10V for a NI fieldpoint data acq

Tags: voltage-measurement

In order to record the temperature in a vacuum chamber, I have a watlow PM9C1FA-AAAAAAA that outputs a 0-24V signal from a type K thermocouple. The data acquisition system that it is connected to is an older NI fieldpoint that reads a 0-10 volt signal. Naturally as the signal gets above 10V on the watlow the data acq maxes out.

How should I go about converting the 0-24V signal so that my data acq can read it as 0-10V?

Comment: Look up voltage dividers. This will introduce some error due to resistor tolerance, but it may be acceptable in a thermocouple system.

Comment: As Spehro says below, this unit is 24 V DC powered (standard industrial control voltage). The output can be configured for 0 - 10 V and not 0 to 24 V.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [quick start guide](http://www.anderson-bolds.com/Merchant2/graphics/00000001/watlow_controls/pdfs/Watlow_EZ_Zone_PM_Quick_Start_Guide.pdf) I see (and which you should have linked) the **process output** is either 0-10V or 4-20mA current loop.

[image]

So if you configure it for 0-10V rather than the current loop you should not have to do anything else.

Do keep in mind that if your thermocouple is grounded-junction, an inexpensive instrument like this one (which does not appear from my brief review of the datasheet to have galvanic isolation) together with a data acquisition system which has a ground as well - the system will not likely work properly.

Comment: @Richard Crowley That would be extremely an extremely rare option, in my experience, so I'll just cling to my interpretation until actual data comes along that conflicts with it, if you don't mind. The maximum loading is also a factor, and I wouldn't care to guess that without data.

Answer (score 0):

You need to build a voltage divider. This is easy normally uses only two resistors.

For best results, you should find out what the output impedance of the temperature meter and the input impedance of the NI system.

More to come.